# .net HttpClient with custom JsonConverter

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using .NET's HttpClient to make requests to a WebAPI that returns some JSON data that requires a little bit of custom deserialization on the client's side.  For this I've made my own `JsonConverter`, but I can't figure out how to have the `ReadAsAsync<T>` method pick up the existence of the converter.

I've solved my problem for now by using `ReadAsStringAsync` to read the response, then passing that string in to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, but it seems like there should be a more elegant solution.

Here's my code:

```
public PrefsResponse GetAllPrefs(string sid) {
    HttpClient client = CreateHttpClient(null, sid);
    var response = client.GetAsync("api/sites/" + sid).Result;

    // TODO : find a way to hook custom converters to this...
    // return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PrefsResponse>().Result;

    var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PrefsResponse>(stringResult, new PrefClassJsonConverter());
}
```

Is this the best I can do, or is there some more elegant way?

Here's where I'm creating the HttpClient also, if that's where I need to hook it up:

```
        private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(CommandContext ctx, string sid) {
        var cookies = new CookieContainer();

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
            CookieContainer = cookies,
            UseCookies = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        // Add identity cookies:
        if (ctx != null && !ctx.UserExecuting.IsAnonymous) {
            string userName = String.Format("{0} ({1})", ctx.RequestingUser.UserName, ctx.UserExecuting.Key);
            cookies.Add(new Cookie(__userIdCookieName, userName));
            cookies.Add(new Cookie(__sidCookieName, sid));
            cookies.Add(new Cookie(__hashCookieName,
                                   GenerateHash(userName, Prefs.Instance.UrlPrefs.SharedSecret)));
        }

        var client = new HttpClient(handler) {
            BaseAddress = _prefServerBaseUrl
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));



        return client;
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass the `JsonSerializerSettings` with the list of your converters to the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` which will be used by `ReadAsAsync<T>`:

i.e.

```
var obj = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<refsResponse>(
    new[] {new JsonMediaTypeFormatter {
          SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { 
              Converters = new List<JsonConverter> {
                //list of your converters
               }
             } 
          }
    });
```

Comment: I had no idea JSON.Net had it's own notion of converters!  So now we have three things that can do the same job.  Derived HttpContent classes, derived MediaTypeFormatters and derived JsonConverter....

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Ultimately I'm going with what I originally had though since I also need to cache the response on disk in case of failovers on future requests.

Comment: Wonderful! I needed to customize some other JSON.NET settings and this was the missing piece of the puzzle for me :)

Comment: @filip-w Is there some way to do this so that the alternate serializer is the default (i.e. doesn't have to be passed in as a parameter)?

Comment: In WebAPi it's easy to configure global json converters, but in client applications, using `HttpClient` I couldn't find an easy way. The question was about the *reading* the response, but what about `POST`ing the request? I have to applies 2 custom formatters, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

May be you would like to use [HttpClient.GetStringAsync Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746.aspx)

```
var response = client.GetStringAsync("api/sites/" + sid);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PrefsResponse>(response.Result, new  PrefClassJsonConverter());
```

Or what exactly you want to be more elegant?

Comment: This is definitely more elegant than passing a hell of nested initializers to the `Content.ReadAsAsync()`. The only cons is probably reading the stream into a string which is more than fine for not very big json packets. I changed my code this way after it went out the code editor window, and no formatting helps with it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add a custom JsonConverter to the default formatters for HttpClient with the following:

```
MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters = new MediaTypeFormatterCollection(); 
formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyCustomConverter());


var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(formatters).Result;
```

This seemed to allow you to just add your custom converter to the default converters.

Comment: what about when using the `httpclient.PostAsJson()`? how can I pass custom formatters?