# Json.NET StringEnumConverter not working as expected

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm attempting to use Json.NET with the System.Net.Http.HttpClient to send an object with an enum property, however the enum is always serialized as an integer value rather than the string equivalent.

I've tried following the instructions here:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data

By both adding an instance of StringEnumConverter to the JsonSerializerSettings and also tried to decorate the enum property with `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` neither of which appear to be working in my example.

I'm using Json.NET version 5.0.8

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?  Here is a sample console app to replicate showing both the global serializer settings and the decorated property:

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test-uri.com") };

            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = (() =>
            {
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                return settings;
            });

            var data = new TestData { Enum = TestEnum.Hello };

            // The following posts: {"Enum":0}
            // Shouldn't it post {"Enum":"Hello"} instead?
            var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/test", data).Result;
        }

        public class TestData
        {
            [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
            public TestEnum Enum { get; set; }
        }

        public enum TestEnum
        {
            Hello,
            World
        }
    }
}
```

I've inspected this with Fiddler and it posts: `{"Enum":0}` rather than `{"Enum":"Hello"}` which is what I would expect.

Comment: Could it be, that you are not using the JsonConverter at all in your example? The serialization is made by the client object - HttpClient. I tried serializing the data object using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data) and the output was correct: {"Enum":"Hello"}. So i think the HttpClient does not convert the enum to string.

Comment: You could well be right.  I was under the impression that the HttpClient used Json.NET under the hood now.  Perhaps I was wrong.  I'll have a tinker and see what I can find.

Comment: It appears that it is using Json.NET under the hood - see Jeff's answer below.

Comment: Well, i didn't knew that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `ItemConverterType` property of the `JsonPropertyAttribute` attribute is the converter to use for items of a collection.  You should be using the `JsonConverterAttribute` attribute.

```
public class TestData
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public TestEnum Enum { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That works thanks!  Do you have any ideas why the DefaultSettings aren't working too?  As I'd prefer not to have to decorate my classes with serialization attributes if possible, but if I have to I will.  Thanks again.

Comment: It should work as you have it right there, assuming that Json.net is actually doing the serializing, not the default serializer used in the `PostAsJsonAsync()` method. If it's not possible to override which serializer to use, it might be easier to serialize using Json.net, then post the resulting string.

Comment: @JeffMercado In your answer, should the order of "TestEnum" and "Enum" be inversed ?

Comment: @Alex: No, `TestEnum` is the name of the type of the property. `Enum` is the name of the property. If they were reversed (?), then they would have a very different meaning.

Answer (score 9):

I think I've found a way of getting it to work without decorating attributes.  It involves replacing `client.PostAsJsonAsync()` with `client.PostAsync()`.  You can then specify the MediaTypeFormatter to use which in this case will be the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`.

Source here: [.net HttpClient with custom JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915485/net-httpclient-with-custom-jsonconverter)

```
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter { SerializerSettings = settings };
    var response = client.PostAsync("/test", data, formatter).Result;
```

This still doesn't explain why the DefaultSettings aren't being applied.  I can only assume that the presence of the `[JsonConverter]` property forces the HttpClient to use Json.NET for serialization, otherwise it just uses the default serializer.

Comment: DefaultSettings are not applied because `PostAsJsonAsync` calls `new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()` which creates new instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` and bypasses default settings. It is wrong and annoying.

Comment: Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks