# Deserialize Dictionary<string, object> with enum values in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, enums

I am trying to serialize/deserialize a `Dictionary<string, object>` in C#.
Object can be anything that is serializable.

Json.NET almost works, but if a value within the dictionary is an `enum`, the deserialization is not correct, as it gets deserialized as a `long`. `TypeNameHandling.All` does not make any difference.

Is there any other fast solution to serialization library. The result does not have to be JSON, but must be text.

I also have no influence on the data that is passed to the dictionary. I just have to serialize and deserialize anything that comes into my way.

EDIT: `StringEnumConverter` does not help. The data gets converted back to `Dictionary<string, object>`, so the deserializer does not know that the serialized value is an `enum`. It treats it like an object, with `StringEnumConverter` it remains a `string` when deserialized; it gets deserialized as a `long` without the converter. JSON.NET does not preserve the enum.

The solution i want to provide is an implementation of an existing interface that gets injected into an existing solution that i cannot change.

EDIT2: Here is an example of what i am trying to do

```
public enum Foo { A, B, C }
public enum Bar { A, B, C }
public class Misc { public Foo Foo { get; set; } }


var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("a", Foo.A);
dict.Add("b", Bar.B);
dict.Add("c", new Misc());

// serialize dict to a string s
// deserialize s to a Dictionary<string, object> dict2

Assert.AreEqual(Foo.A, dict2["a"]);
Assert.AreEqual(Bar.B, dict2["b"]);
```

Important: i cannot control `dict`; it is actually a custom type that is derived from `Dictionary<string, object>`: I just have to make sure that all keys and values deserialized are from the same type when deserialized, so that no casting is needed. And again, i do not have to use JSON; maybe there is some other serializer that can handle the job!?

Comment: As enums are by default integers, so it does get serialized as a number, but in case you have a control over deserialization too, then it shall be an automatic conversion

Comment: When you say say you have no control over the data, does that mean you don't have the ability to add an attribute to the enum such as `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`?

Comment: Also check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731192/json-net-stringenumconverter-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON serialization of enum as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string)

Comment: `TypeNameHandling` does not work for enums because they are serialized as strings or numbers, not objects, so there's no opportunity for a `"$type"` to be included.  You need to wrap them in something to convey the type, see [Deserialize specific enum into system.enum in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351262) for one such wrapper.  As for how to inject this into your existing solution, please share some example code.  A custom contract resolver or converter might be one possibility.

Comment: i added an example code of what i want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you are already serializing your dictionary with [`TypeNameHandling.All`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm), which should correctly serialize and deserialize the `new Misc()` value by emitting a [`"$type"`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) object property along with the object itself.  Unfortunately, for types such as enums (and others such as as `int` and `long`), this doesn't work because these are serialized as JSON primitives, with no opportunity to include a `"$type"` property.

The solution is, when serializing a dictionary with `object` values, to serialize object wrappers for primitive values that can encapsulate the type information, along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351262/deserialize-specific-enum-into-system-enum-in-json-net/31353162#31353162).  Since you cannot modify any of your incoming objects and need to "inject" the proper wrappers, you can do this with a custom contract resolver that applies an appropriate [item converter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) to the dictionary values:

```
public class UntypedToTypedValueContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
    // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."
    // See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557737/does-json-net-cache-types-serialization-information
    static UntypedToTypedValueContractResolver instance;

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static UntypedToTypedValueContractResolver() { instance = new UntypedToTypedValueContractResolver(); }

    public static UntypedToTypedValueContractResolver Instance { get { return instance; } }

    protected override JsonDictionaryContract CreateDictionaryContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateDictionaryContract(objectType);

        if (contract.DictionaryValueType == typeof(object) && contract.ItemConverter == null)
        {
            contract.ItemConverter = new UntypedToTypedValueConverter();
        }

        return contract;
    }
}

class UntypedToTypedValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This converter should only be applied directly via ItemConverterType, not added to JsonSerializer.Converters");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        if (value is TypeWrapper)
        {
            return ((TypeWrapper)value).ObjectValue;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (serializer.TypeNameHandling == TypeNameHandling.None)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ObjectItemConverter used when serializer.TypeNameHandling == TypeNameHandling.None");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
        // Handle a couple of simple primitive cases where a type wrapper is not needed
        else if (value is string)
        {
            writer.WriteValue((string)value);
        }
        else if (value is bool)
        {
            writer.WriteValue((bool)value);
        }
        else
        {
            var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());
            if (contract is JsonPrimitiveContract)
            {
                var wrapper = TypeWrapper.CreateWrapper(value);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, wrapper, typeof(object));
            }
            else
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            }
        }
    }
}

public abstract class TypeWrapper
{
    protected TypeWrapper() { }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public abstract object ObjectValue { get; }

    public static TypeWrapper CreateWrapper<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new TypeWrapper<T>();
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(T))
            return new TypeWrapper<T>(value);
        // Return actual type of subclass
        return (TypeWrapper)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TypeWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(type), value);
    }
}

public sealed class TypeWrapper<T> : TypeWrapper
{
    public TypeWrapper() : base() { }

    public TypeWrapper(T value)
        : base()
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override object ObjectValue { get { return Value; } }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    ContractResolver = UntypedToTypedValueContractResolver.Instance,
    Converters = new [] { new StringEnumConverter() }, // If you prefer
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented, settings);

var dict2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json, settings);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y0EQKP).

Finally, when using `TypeNameHandling`, do take note of this caution from the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to modify the **object** class, you can add the JsonCoverter attribute to the enum member of the class.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
```

Comment: no, i don't. I implement an interface, that gets injected via Dependency Injection into an closed application.

Comment: Can you please update your post with an example of what you?