# How to convert only given type even if it is stored as object?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

The background of this story is de/serializing `U/Int64` as strings with wrappers, but the problem is more basic. I have such test class:

```
class Any
{
    public object Value;
}
```

`Value` could be of any type, of course now I am testing it for `U/Int64`. My read converter checks for my two wrappers (for `Int64` and `UInt64`) but it also has to answer `true` for type `object` (otherwise `ReadJson` is not called for it):

```
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(System.Object).Equals(objectType)
            || typeof(UInt64Wrapper).Equals(objectType)
            || typeof(Int64Wrapper).Equals(objectType);
    }
```

The problem is, since I registered for `Object` my converter now runs in loop when it comes to `ReadJson`:

```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                    object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType); // loop
        if (value is Int64Wrapper)
            value = Int64.Parse(((Int64Wrapper)value).Value);
        else if (value is UInt64Wrapper)
            value = UInt64.Parse(((UInt64Wrapper)value).Value);
        return value;
    }
```

Because my converter declared it can read `object` when I call `serializer.Deserialize`, my method is called, I call `Deserialize` again and so on.

So how could I register my converter that I have business only with my two wrappers so I could avoid this infinite loop?

*Class `Any` is mine, but in general I cannot use any decorations in this class. All I can do is configure json.net serializer, its settings, add converters, and so on, but data classes are untouchable.*

Update: code example:

```
class Any
{
    public object Value;
}

class Test
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var example = new Any() { Value = 0 };
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            ContractResolver = UntypedToTypedPropertyContractResolver.Instance,
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(example, Formatting.Indented, settings);
        var example2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Any>(json, settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the `UntypedToTypedPropertyContractResolver` + `UntypedToTypedValueConverter` combination from [JSON.net (de)serialize untyped property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777588/json-net-deserialize-untyped-property).  Using a custom contract resolver to add the converter to each `object`-type property avoids the infinite recursion.

Comment: Actually, is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777588/json-net-deserialize-untyped-property an exact duplicate?  It looks as though you're also trying to add a wrapper to a primitive type so its type information can be serialized.

Comment: @dbc, thank you, I hope I am not going in circles, because you already helped me with the untyped properties :-) However here is flipped case -- I **cannot** change class, so I have to declare my converter globally. I will look in contract resolver.

Comment: @dbc, small update. History :-) -- my original idea was having combined two approaches -- converting unknown types as you pointed out **and** adding second converter, just for `Int64` type (which would wrap it in its own Wrapper, holding `string` internally). Now, I tried single converter which do both actions, and contract resolver as well -- however now `ReadJson` is not called (only `Write`).

Comment: I can't guess why it isn't called, I'd have to see a [mcve].

Comment: @dbc, oh, there is really nothing more to add, but just in case -- please see the update, the rest is copy&paste from the post you linked here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777588/json-net-deserialize-untyped-property). I.e. converter + contract resolver + type wrappers. To check the write is not called you can set the breakpoint in the body of it, or you can check the content of the deserialization -- `example2` will hold `TypeWrapper`.

Comment: I found and fixed a bug the the `UntypedToTypedPropertyContractResolver` from that answer, and updated the answer.

Comment: @dbc, thank you very very much! My current solution is one converter and one resolver which handles both cases -- handling `U/Int64` (strongly typed or not) and untyped objects. I don't know whether it is recommended approach (vs. two converters + 2 resolvers) but... it **works**. Could you please post any of your comments as answer and I will be happy to mark it as solution.

Comment: one converter and one resolver sound good to me.  I don't think I really said anything new in comments though, so why don't I mark this as a duplicate?