# Newtonsoft.Json, can you maintain type information with list of object?

Tags: json.net

Is there some way to serialize and then deserialize a list of object and maintain type information? Very simple sample but type is lost on all elements of the list. The resulting json only has type information for the List.

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
        var list = new List<object> { Guid.NewGuid(), "hello", 72, new Uri("http://microsoft.com")};
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, settings);
        list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings) as List<object>;
```

Comment: Take a look at [JSON.net (de)serialize untyped property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38777588/3744182) and [Deserialize Dictionary<string, object> with enum values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38336390/3744182).   Are those sufficient, or do you need a more specific answer?  But also see [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It answered my question but in the end I believe we will be changing our serialization back to DataContract as it handles this and other things better.