# C# - Office API returning 400 "69 {"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"Cannot read the value '0' as a quoted JSON string value."}} 0 "

Tags: c#, json, post, office365api

I'm trying to send email using the Office 365 API, I can't use the Microsoft.Office365 packages for sending, as they don't currently support our authentication, but I do have a valid token to access the API, get requests work perfectly, but when I try to post to "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail" I get the above error. While I can't use the send functions provided in Microsoft.Office365 I am using the message object to create my emails then serializing and posting.

```
public void SendMail(string Subject, string Body) {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string accessToken = userCache.UserAccessToken;
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", agent);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client-request-id", requestGuid);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("return-client-request-id", "true");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    List<string> recipients = new List<string>();
    recipients.Add(userCache.Email);

    #region Create Email Message
    Message email = new Message();
    email.Body = new ItemBody();
    email.Body.Content = Body;
    email.Body.ContentType = 0;//0=text, 1=html
    email.From = new Recipient();
    email.From.EmailAddress = new EmailAddress();
    email.From.EmailAddress.Address = userCache.Email;//set from email to email of current logged in user

    email.Importance = Importance.Normal;
    email.Sender = email.From;
    email.Subject = Subject;
    email.ToRecipients = recipients;
    #endregion
    try {
        dynamic mailObject = new ExpandoObject();
        mailObject.Message = email;
        mailObject.SaveToSentItems = "true";
        HttpResponseMessage hrm = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Object>(uri, mailObject as ExpandoObject).Result;
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

This submits the json below to the API:

```
{
    "Message": {
        "Subject": "Products",
        "Body": {
            "ContentType": 0,
            "Content": "Products"
        },
        "BodyPreview": null,
        "Importance": 0,
        "HasAttachments": null,
        "ParentFolderId": null,
        "From": {
            "EmailAddress": {
                "Name": null,
                "Address":"andrew.branoff@paretobiz.com"
            }
        },
        "Sender": {
            "EmailAddress": {
                "Name": null,
                "Address": "andrew.branoff@paretobiz.com"
            }
        },
        "ToRecipients": [
            {
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Name": null,
                    "Address": "andrew.branoff@paretobiz.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "CcRecipients": [],
        "BccRecipients": [],
        "ReplyTo": [],
        "ConversationId": null,
        "UniqueBody": null,
        "DateTimeReceived": null,
        "DateTimeSent": null,
        "IsDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
        "IsReadReceiptRequested": null,
        "IsDraft": null,
        "IsRead": null,
        "WebLink": null,
        "Attachments": [],
        "ChangeKey": null,
        "Categories": [],
        "DateTimeCreated": null,
        "DateTimeLastModified": null,
        "Id": null
    },
    "SaveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

As far as I can tell this is what the API is looking for, since I used their own object to build it, but it seems to reject what I send no matter what I do. I have tried serializing first using

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mailObject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

to not send the null values, figuring it might not accept values, even null, for things it calculates like the body preview, but no change.

Comment: The error indicates that you are sending an integer value `0` when the API expects a string value.  And in fact the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) shows that `Message.Body.ContentType` should be a string: `"ContentType": "Text"`.

Comment: You're absolutely right @dbc I just find it strange their API expects something different from what the object meant to be sent to the API contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you are sending an integer value `0` when the API expects a string value.  And in fact the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) shows that `Message.Body.ContentType` as well `Message.Importance` should be strings, e.g:

```
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "Text",
    "Content": "Products"
  },
```

You are likely sending integer values for these properties because, in your c# classes, they are enums.  If you want to serialize enums as strings by name, you need to use [`StringEnumConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_converters_stringenumconverter.htm).

You could set it directly on the property as an attribute, e.g.:

```
public class Body
{ 
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ContentType ContentType { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

You could also configure `HttpClient` to use this converter for all enums as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731192/json-net-stringenumconverter-not-working-as-expected/19732845#19732845).

Comment: Yeah that was it. Strange their object is built in such a way it can't be serialized and sent without reverting the Enums.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the specified error occurs since the provided JSON payload is invalid.

The issue is related with this line:

```
email.Body.ContentType = 0;//0=text, 1=html
```

`ContentType` property of [`Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemBody`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#ItemBody) accepts *string* values (not *integer*): `Text` or `HTML`, for example:

```
email.Body.ContentType = "Text";
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, it does not accept strings in the code: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.BodyType'` but this looks like the right track, sounds like the API is looking for a string while their class is built with an integer/enum.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help given by the other answers, I found my solution, to modify the way Json.net serializes the object. I'm posting the exact solution to help anyone else with this issue later on.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailObject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, settings);
StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```