# Asynchronous task deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpclient

I have an async method that works when used with the .Result property, but not when using the await keyword. I thought using await instead of result was correct.  Am I wrong?

```
// doesn't work - hangs
protected async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri) =>
    await ParseJson<T>(await Client.GetAsync(uri));

// works
protected async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri) =>
    await ParseJson<T>(Client.GetAsync(uri).Result);
```

The Client in the above code is a HttpClient, and the ParseJson method is as follows:

```
protected async Task<T> ParseJson<T>(HttpResponseMessage response) =>
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), Settings);
```

The code is being run in an asp.net mvc application if that makes any difference.

**Update**
Fixed. Thanks to:
@Igor - You were correct, the MVC controllor action calling the method was not asynchronous and was therefore using .Result instead of await.
@Panagiotis - I've split my code out as you suggested to make it more debuggable.

Comment: Can you please share Client.GetAsync functions source?

Comment: Post code that can reproduce the problem. What you posted, once cleaned up, is the typical way of using HttpClient. For example, `ParseJson` isn't an asynchronous function, it simply mixes up `ReadAsStringAsync` with `Deserialize`. Your code would actually be cleaner if you *separated* the calls. At least this way you could debug the code and see *which* line blocks, if any

Comment: Typical call with HttpClient that *doesn't* block: `var response=await client.Get(uri); var text=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();var myItem=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text,settings);`. That's what your code does, in a way that prevents actual debugging.

Comment: It is code you are not showing us, most likely you tried using `async/await` BUT one of the implementations not shown is using `.Result` (like the implementation of `Client.GetAsync(string)`, ie. code in that method).

Comment: PS You can get rid of `ParseJson` entirely. HttpClient allows you to use your own Json converter to deserialize objets. By default it uses the old JavascriptSerializer but you can instruct it to use Json.NET [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915485/net-httpclient-with-custom-jsonconverter). Your  code can be as simple as  `var response=await client.GetAsync(uri); var myItem=await responce.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(formatter);`