# How to configure json deserialization with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

So I'm using asp.net core 2.2, and adding the http client the following way:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IDeviceClient, DeviceClient>();
```

In my `DeviceClient` i use the following code:

```cs
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync($"http://{ipAddress}/sensors/scan");
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<SensorInfo[]>();
```

Currently the `HttpClient` does the deserialization for me but how do i configure it?

When you do the json deserialization on your own you can add a `JsonSerializerSettings` parameter, is there some way top add this while calling `AddHttpClient`?

Comment: are you using the Web API Client library?

Comment: @DanielA.White I dont think so but I'm not 100% sure but the `AddHttpClient` is part of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` assembly.

Comment: @Peter short answer: NO.

Comment: @Nkosi no as in i dont use Web API or no as in you can't.

Comment: @Peter sorry, No as in not a  way to add this while calling AddHttpClient

Comment: But you can use it with the response content as stated https://stackoverflow.com/a/13916838/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi nice that will solve my problem, would have preferred to do it when calling AddHttpClient but i will take what i can get!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.net HttpClient with custom JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915485/net-httpclient-with-custom-jsonconverter)